# Strange grep output

Tags: regex, grep, ubuntu-10.10

Shouldn't `echo "ab" | grep "[A-B]"` return nothing? Strangely it returns `ab`

LE:
Apparently on older versions of Ubuntu (9.10) there's no problem, only 10.10 has this

Comment: Is that **exactly** your command line ?

Comment: Run the command `alias`. It will list out your aliases. You probably have `alias grep='grep -i'`.

Comment: Yes, it's probably an alias. I don't have it defined on my system.

Comment: yes, that's exactly my command line. these are the only aliases for grep: alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'     alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'     alias grep='grep --color=auto'

Comment: I think it's safe to say that this is grep bug and should be reported to grep developers. I can confirm it with grep 2.6.3

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't return anything on my system.

Comment: Doesn't return any on mine either. What platform are you on @titus?

Comment: ubuntu 10.10 Maverick Meerkat

Answer (score 0):

Need use grep -i, to ignore case of characters

Comment: Yes. I was wrong. My eanglish is bad. I think you grep is color-select math part. echo "ab" | grep -o "[A-B]" - does not return nothing